# Plone external editor problem

Tags: plone

I've some problem with external editor (plone 3.3.5): the opened editor show me only, i suppose, mime type data and not the content of the document.
Some suggests to solve this problem?
Regards,
Michele

Comment: does this happen with all content types? Does this happen with a fresh new install?

Comment: Yes, it happen in a fresh new install and also with the other content type.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely do not have the External Editor helper application installed on your computer. The `External Editor` link in Plone sends a special file (the mime type data you see in your editor) that normally would be opened by the helper application.

What platform are you on? You can download the [External Editor](http://plone.org/products/external-editor) package and re-install the helper application for your platform. Note that for Mac, there is a separate package called [Zope Edit Manager](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/13986/zopeeditmanager) to install.

There are some rather dated troubleshooting and configuration instructions available for [Windows](http://plope.org/software/ExternalEditor/install-win32) and [Unix](http://plope.org/software/ExternalEditor/install-unix) in case automated installers fail. These instructions haven't been updated in years though.